# Drupal 7 push-worker.js

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a site in Drupal 7 which somewhere this push-worker.js gets call on every load on my page and I cannot figure out where and how this is called. I tried searching the entire DB and project files and nothing.

If you have any ideas please let me know

Comment: push-worker.js is not part of drupal core and we don't know your site or even what modules you have installed, so anyone trying to help you will just be guessing.

Comment: Did you have PWA module installed ? it's look like a service worker , so maybe you have a module who needs this to work . Check your modules and try to find it (like browser notification, or chat , etc..)